# What recommended? Bootstrap 4 or 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

When Bootstrap 4 came out im trying to learn the new methods but it does not works fully.

Is it recommended to now learn Bootstrap 4 or just wait for bootstrap 4 when it comes fully out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now, **Bootstrap 4 is still in beta stage**. If you are thinking about being prepared for the future, it makes sense. If you needs it right now, maybe there's a risk on it. Of course, there are plent of other good CSS frameworks out there with stable releases and many resources similar to the next Bootstrap, like Foundation, Bulma, Pure, Framework 7 etc.

Comment: Actually it's in beta now

Comment: I thought it was in beta

Comment: Yes, it's in beta, I was wrong while writing. I have already updated.